# GestureDetector Not Working

Tags: android, tabs, actionbarsherlock, swipe, gesture-recognition

I have implemented Sherlock Action Bar tab view.Now i want to swipe tabs by using gesture detector.My Tab View is working perfectly.But i want to fire tabselected event while swipeing the screen using gesture listner .Here is the code snippet.

```
 package com.cdotsys.newsfeed;





  public class HomeActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements   OnTouchListener,ActionBar.TabListener {


 ActionBar.Tab Tab1,Tab2;



GestureDetector gestureDetector;
View mainview;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

   Tab1 = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
   Tab2 = getSupportActionBar().newTab();

    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new MyGestureDetector());
    mainview = (View) findViewById(R.id.test);
    mainview.setOnTouchListener(this);
    // Hide Actionbar Icon
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

    // Hide Actionbar Title
   actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    // Create Actionbar Tabs
   actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Set Tab Icon and Titles
    Tab1.setText("Tab1");
    Tab2.setText("Tab2");

    // Set Tab Listeners
    Tab1.setTabListener(this);
    Tab2.setTabListener(this);


    // Add tabs to actionbar
    actionBar.addTab(Tab1);
    actionBar.addTab(Tab2);

}

 class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener implements OnGestureListener {
    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;


    @Override
    public boolean onFling(final MotionEvent e1, final MotionEvent e2, final float velocityX, final float velocityY) {
        if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH) {  return false;  }

        /* positive value means right to left direction */
        final float distance = e1.getX() - e2.getX();
        final boolean enoughSpeed = Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY;
        if(distance > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && enoughSpeed) {
            // right to left swipe
            return true;
        } else {
            // oooou, it didn't qualify; do nothing
            return false;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)){

        System.out.println("Working!!");
         return true;

    }

    return false;

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("SimpleActionBarTabsActivity","tab "
            + String.valueOf(tab.getPosition()) + " clicked");
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("SimpleActionBarTabsActivity","tab "
            + String.valueOf(tab.getPosition()) + " un-clicked");
}


@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

 }
```

Here is my XML files

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/test"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".HomeActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

Here i have used View mainview = (View) findViewById(R.id.test);

here test is the id of Relative layout which i am using as setContentView..

Is it correct? What are the modification should i need to follow to achieve the tabselected event fired by using gesturelistner ?

Please help !!

Answer (score 4):

I have found the bug in my code..Needed to implement onDown

```
@Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) 
    {            
     return true;
    }
```

Now the code is working.One have to implement this while extending SimpleOnGestureListener.